# having a translucent background without affecting its containing elements

Tags: html, css

I basically want to overlay a web pattern over a background image and reduce the opacity of the web pattern because, I want the background to be slightly visible, now I quick look at the documentation, reveals the following ::

> Syntactically a <number>. The uniform opacity setting to be applied
>   across an entire object. Any values outside the range 0.0 (fully
>   transparent) to 1.0 (fully opaque) will be clamped to this range. If
>   the object is a container element, then the effect is as if the
>   contents of the container element were blended against the current
>   background using a mask where the value of each pixel of the mask is
>   <alphavalue>.  **[W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/)**

now I have the following code so far:

CSS and HTML ::

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/1920x1200/2011/Space_Huge_explosion_031412_.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.wrapper * {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.dell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: url(http://image.clipdealer.com/1140524/previews/18--1140524-Electronic%20dots%20Background,particle,mosaics,puzzle,tech%20communication,web%20enery,disco%20neon,game,grid,weaving,textile,pattern,symbol,vision,idea,creativity,vj,beautiful,art,decorative,mind,Geometry,mathematics,computing,graphics,fun,Game,Led,neon%20lights,mo.jpg);
  opacity: 0;
}
.orange {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background: orange;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="dell">
    <div class="orange">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

now opacity achieves the objective of showing through the background, but of course, the contents of `.dell` become translucent too, now is there a solution to this in which I can have a show through background without having the contents of `.dell` getting translucent?

I would preferably not link the background and the translucent pattern to be merged together.

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/7xo353hg/6/)**

Comment: which element class is your background? wrapper or dell?

Comment: wrapper is the background and dell is the translucent overlay !

Comment: try .orange {
 .....;opacity:1;
}

Comment: also you can do this:      .dell:after{.....;opacity:1;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/7xo353hg/8/

```
.dell:after{
    width:200px;
    content:'';
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:0;
    margin-left:-100px;
    background:orange;
    opacity: .5;
    z-index:0;
    display:block;
}
```